# Invalid object name : database object doesn't exist anymore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with 3 projects
- MVC4 website
- HTTP Handler
- Entity Framework data layer

Basicaly you have to fill out a form on the website, that transforms it into XML, sends it to the handler that returns XML and the website deals with the response. Both applications use the data layer library to update a database.

I've been doing test with the handler running localy and remotely on a webserver running IIS8. The first version I put on the webserver was working all right. Then I had to update the data layer library, and now i'm getting the "Invalid object name" error.

The thing is, the object anme is a table name that does not exist anymore in my data layer project, which really sounds weird to me.

I checked probably everything I could
- Connection strings are ok
- Rights to the database are ok
- the handler's DLL is up to dae
- the library' dll is up to date

I even stoped and restarted the application pool in which my handler is. Even now I tried it again with the handler running localy and it works fine, the error only happens when calling the handler on the remote server, and only since I made changes to the data layer library.

The only thing I think might be the cause is if there was something cached somewhere that I didn't know of.

Here's the stack trace, altough I didn't find any helpful information in it

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```